# calculating the file size from the file path in a string

Tags: c, file, network-programming

A little premise: A server is receiving by socket a message "get text.txt"
I have to compute the size of that file and send it back so here is the code so far:

```
                /*Receive command
                *
                */
                char * file_path;

                //Wait for command
                if ( recvfrom (sockfd_child, command, PACKET_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) addr_client, &addr_client_lenght) < 0) {
                    perror("server: error in recvfrom for command packet");
                    exit(1);
                }
                //check first 4 character (COMMAND_SIZE) of command packet send by the client to identify the operation
                if (!strncmp(command, "get ", COMMAND_SIZE)) {
                    file_path = malloc(sizeof(command)-COMMAND_SIZE);
                    strcpy(file_path, DIRECTORY);
                    strncat(file_path, command+COMMAND_SIZE, PACKET_SIZE-COMMAND_SIZE);
                    printf("Getting file in path: '%s'\n", file_path);
                    int file_size = get_file_size(file_path);
```

The function to calculate the file_size is

```
long get_file_size(char * file_name) {
  long size;
    FILE * file;
  if ( !( file = fopen ( file_name , "rb" ) ) ) {
    perror("file: error calculating size");
    exit (1);
  }
  fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
  size = ftell (file);
  rewind (file);
  fclose(file);
  return size;
}
```

DIRECTORY is a constant and is set to ./files/ 
COMMAND_SIZE is set at 4 
The network part of the program works well, the command string is successfully transmitted. 
the program stops in the function at perror printing `file: error calculating size: No such file or directory` but the previous printf prints the currect path where the file is located `Getting file in path: './files/text.txt'` 
So I guess the error is in how I separate the file path from the command 'get' or somewhere else i cannot grasp. Can you help me? Sorry for any mistake or confusion but it's 4:00AM here :)

Comment: please make an example that can be tested by others, see instructions here too.http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: Wild guess, since you're working with a relative path: the working directory of the server process is probably not what you think it is. Get and print the current working directory with `getcwd`; does `./files/test.txt` exist relative to that directory?

Comment: In calculating file size, consider the functions `fsetpos()` and `fgetpos()`.  The integer used in those is the right size for the OS.  `long`, as used by `fseek()` and `ftell()` may be insufficient.

Comment: @Wintermute turns out you're right as rain, i checked the working directory and found that i put the files directory in a subdirectory of it (\Release) that is where the executable is, I thought was correct.

Answer (score 0):

It will sound obvious, but try a     "printf"    to verify the name of the file and the path to it. Maybe there is a problem with the blanks or something. Btw, you can use scripts to calculate the size of the file (if you are in linux, you have a lot of commands to do it), and pass the value as an argument to the program.

Answer (score 0):

See your malloc(). It only allocate `sizeof(command)-COMMAND_SIZE` for `file_path`. But it need to store `strlen(DIRECTORY) + sizeof(command)-COMMAND_SIZE`. `strncat()` and `printf()` do not check whether the array wil be out of bound so you get a right ouput of `file_path`.

You can replace `file_name` with `./files/text.txt` in `get_file_size()` to check it.

Comment: Qmick Zh, what you are saying makes sense but it works without the modifications youre suggesting, simply by moving the file in the correct working directory (and print the correct file dimension too...how so?)